# CD4059 behavior with invalid jam inputs

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, clock

I am currently working on a circuit for a electronic synth module that should function as a random clock generator. My idea is to use a high frequency clock (relatively speaking for musical application ~ 1200 bpm = 20 Hz) and divide it using programmable counter.
I already have a couple of CD4059 ICs and it seems that they are suitable for this application.
According to the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/cd4059a) CD4059 can be configured in couple of different modes - but the most straightforward forward for random divisor seems to be this:
[image]
This mode allows me to configure ones, tens, hundreds and thousands of divisor separately via switches and feed random bits to some/all of them.
The question that I have is following - minimal divisor number that CD4059 is rated for is N=3 - what is unclear for me from the datasheet is what happens if you set jam inputs with invalid values that give N=1 or N=2 (this can occur for me based on the randomness of my inputs) - does the CD4059 stop producing output?

If anyone had experience with this IC I would appreciate your response or direction to a datasheet section.

Comment: What is a "random clock"? Do you mean a random binary stream of 1s and 0s? If so, then a LFSR will give you a pseudorandom sequence, and an amplified noise of a Zener diode followed by a filter and a comparator will give you nothing-pseudo-about-it noise :)

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica What I meant by "random clock" is this: I use a couple of transistors and CD4015 shift registers to generate 16 bits of jam values. I sample them and latch these values using CD4042 and wait for CD4059 to finish its counting cycle and then sample new random values, etc. This, in my opinion, allows to get more variable intervals (really long as well as short) than just a single random bit-stream.

Comment: What stops you from trying? Clocked digital circuits work determinately, even if the data sheet does not define its behaviour. _If_ the data sheet defines the behaviour, what is the real question you have? (You might want to [edit] your question and add a link to the data sheet you use.)

Comment: @thebusybee My bad, added the link to the datasheet. I did not find the description of this behavior in it. I've decided to ask this question here before trying it because SOIC packaging is not particularly suitable for prototyping on the breadboard and waiting for PCB will take a couple of weeks. In case there are no answers I will of course resort to trying it in hardware:)

Comment: Sadly [the other data sheet by Philips](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/NXP%20PDFs/HEF4059B.pdf) I found has just the same information, but is not a simple scan. I was hoping for a gate level schematic.